# Unable to install Vaadin Testbench via Maven

Tags: maven-2, vaadin

I need test a web application (built on Vaadin) hence I am doing a `proof of concept` for Vaadin Testbench which is a Selenium Wrapper. But I am unable to build the project with the required dependency.

**Error I get is -**

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: com.github.zch:pdfsplit-maven-plugin

Reason: POM 'com.github.zch:pdfsplit-maven-plugin' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifact from any rep
ository

  com.github.zch:pdfsplit-maven-plugin:pom:1.0.1

from the specified remote repositories:
  ...
  vaadin-addons (http://vaadin.com/nexus/content/repositories/vaadin-addons),
  ...
  pdfsplit-plugin (https://raw.github.com/zch/maven/releases/),
  ...

 for project com.github.zch:pdfsplit-maven-plugin
```

**POM.xml (part)**

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-addons</id>
        <url>http://vaadin.com/nexus/content/repositories/vaadin-addons/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-shared</artifactId>
        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>servlet-api-2.5</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
                <groupId>ant</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-client</artifactId>
        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-testbench</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.rc2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.github.zch</groupId>
                <artifactId>pdfsplit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Have you added <pluginrepositories> section in your pom.xml like here https://github.com/zch/pdfsplit-maven-plugin ?

Comment: Post the relevant parts of your pom.xml.

Comment: @Joe I have tried that too and if you see the URL given there is bad [400: Invalid request]

Comment: @SiKing added the partial pom

Comment: as a random side note: is testbench supposed to work with 6.8?

Comment: @cfrick ans is `not related`. That's something which comes later when I get a build success :) Moreover all these Vaadin dependencies work only error comes when I add TestBench!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access to outside repositories is blocked from office network hence I had to manually install the jar for Maven guess earlier I was using the wrong version/command.

I tried this command -

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.vaadin -DartifactId=vaadin-testbench -Dversion=4.0.0.rc2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=C:\Users\Downloads\vaadin-testbench-4.0.0.rc2\maven\vaadin-testbench-4.0.0.rc2.jar
```

Comment: Setup a Nexus repository in your office and allow internet connection only for that particular machine which hosts the nexus. Then you will be able to use maven without fuss.